# Check equilibrium point for stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

$\dot x = -y^2$ 
$\dot y = x^3y$

The task is to draw global phase portrait (I guess I understand how to manage this using isoclines) and to check equilibrium point for stability. I found out that equilibrium points are (x; 0)  and using Jacobian matrix found out, that if x > 0 one of eigenvalues is always positive so points (x, 0) where x > 0 are not stable at all. (Correct me, if I am wrong, please). And I don't know how to check the solutions where x <= 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x^4 + 2 y^2$ is constant on trajectories of this system.  The curves $x^4 + 2 y^2 = c$ are shaped like distorted ellipses.  Any solution in the left half plane will approach the negative $x$ axis along one of these curves.  In particular, the equilibrium points $(x,0)$ for $x \le 0$ are stable (but not asymptotically stable).

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Is it always so that if the solution approaches the equilibrium point then it is stable? And why is it not asymptotically stable?

Comment: Stable: for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that a solution that starts within distance $\delta$ of the equilibrium point stays within $\epsilon$ of it.  That's the case here.

Comment: Asymptotically stable: in addition to being stable, a solution that starts within distance $\delta$ of the equilibrium point goes to that equilibrium point in the limit as $t \to +\infty$.  That is not the case here: it could go instead to some other nearby equilibrium point.

Comment: And what about x > 0? It should also be stable then? The picture of solutions is the same there.

Comment: No.  Look at the phase portrait.  If $x > 0$ the solutions move away from the axis along the curve $x^4 + 2 y^2 = c$, because $\dot{y}$ has the same sign as $y$.

Comment: I'll add a picture to the answer.